# No converter found to convert to interface javax.jms.TextMessage

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am running a spring boot application that connects to activeMQ as a consumer from my Spring STS environment. I then run my camel blueprint from my JBoss Developer Studio app.

Here's the code from my listener:

```
@JmsListener(destination = '${tripRequest.updateStatus.destination}')
void handle(TextMessage message) {
```

When the message hits the consumer, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.xxx.trip.request.messaging.status.TripRequestUpdateStatusListener.handle(javax.jms.TextMessage)]
Bean [com.xxx.trip.request.messaging.status.TripRequestUpdateStatusListener@1a99744a]
; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No converter found to convert to interface javax.jms.TextMessage, message=GenericMessage [payload=byte[197], headers={CamelFileLastModified=1466448102155, CamelFileParent=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data, CamelFilePath=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data\one.json, CamelFileLength=22, jms_destination=queue://tripRequest.updateStatus.v1.0, jms_priority=4, CamelFileAbsolute=true, jms_timestamp=1466631945834, CamelFileName=one.json, jms_redelivered=false, jms_deliveryMode=2, CamelFileNameConsumed=one.json, breadcrumbId=ID-ThomasLaptop-55017-1466631942306-0-1, jms_replyTo=temp-queue://ID:ThomasLaptop-55022-1466631945608-1:1:1, CamelFileRelativePath=one.json, jms_correlationId=Camel-ID-ThomasLaptop-55017-1466631942306-0-3, id=3c38a185-44c7-4df2-fefb-1f3320e0262f, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data\one.json, jms_expiration=1466631965834, jms_messageId=ID:ThomasLaptop-55022-1466631945608-1:1:2:1:1, CamelFileNameOnly=one.json, timestamp=1466631945924}]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:94) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:66) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:721) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:681) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:315) [spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:253) [spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) [spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1150) [spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1047) [spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No converter found to convert to interface javax.jms.TextMessage, message=GenericMessage [payload=byte[197], headers={CamelFileLastModified=1466448102155, CamelFileParent=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data, CamelFilePath=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data\one.json, CamelFileLength=22, jms_destination=queue://tripRequest.updateStatus.v1.0, jms_priority=4, CamelFileAbsolute=true, jms_timestamp=1466631945834, CamelFileName=one.json, jms_redelivered=false, jms_deliveryMode=2, CamelFileNameConsumed=one.json, breadcrumbId=ID-ThomasLaptop-55017-1466631942306-0-1, jms_replyTo=temp-queue://ID:ThomasLaptop-55022-1466631945608-1:1:1, CamelFileRelativePath=one.json, jms_correlationId=Camel-ID-ThomasLaptop-55017-1466631942306-0-3, id=3c38a185-44c7-4df2-fefb-1f3320e0262f, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data\one.json, jms_expiration=1466631965834, jms_messageId=ID:ThomasLaptop-55022-1466631945608-1:1:2:1:1, CamelFileNameOnly=one.json, timestamp=1466631945924}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:118) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:98) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:90) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

I know for a fact that we have tested this with text messages sent from another application and this message works fine. I don't understand why it fails from my camel route. When I look at the message, it appears to be well-formed XML. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tripRequestUpdateStatus>
    <id>1</id>
    <status>Approved</status>
    <updatedBy source="lgtc">1</updatedBy>
</tripRequestUpdateStatus>
```

Why does it need converted in the first place when I'm sending text? Why is conversion failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you created a new question after you found out something, but forgot to mention this in this question: [How to send text message instead of byte message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012400/how-to-send-text-message-instead-of-byte-message)

You send the messages as byte payload so the JMS consumer receives the message payload as a `javax.jms.BytesMessage` which Spring Integration is not able to convert to a `javax.jms.TextMessage`. So you can change your code to use a `javax.jms.BytesMessage` instead. Or have the sender send the JMS messages as Text based instead of Bytes.