# How to send text message instead of byte message

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-jms

I am building a camel route using blueprint.xml that talks to my JMS queue. I have been getting mysterious errors where my spring boot app that acts as a consumer for my queue is sending my xml as a byte message instead of text message and the Spring consumer chokes on this.

Here are the two messages, the text one works:

```
2016-06-24 07:08:22,671 | INFO  | Sending message: ActiveMQBytesMessage {commandId = 8, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:ThomasLaptop-54711-1466766502054-1:1:2:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:ThomasLaptop-54711-1466766502054-1:1:2:1, destination = queue://tripRequest.updateStatus.v1.0, transactionId = null, expiration = 1466766522670, timestamp = 1466766502670, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = Camel-ID-ThomasLaptop-54704-1466766499471-0-3, replyTo = temp-queue://ID:ThomasLaptop-54711-1466766502054-1:1:1, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@149f0268, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@1421b3cd, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {CamelFileLastModified=1466448102155, CamelFileParent=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data, CamelFilePath=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data\one.json, CamelFileNameConsumed=one.json, breadcrumbId=ID-ThomasLaptop-54704-1466766499471-0-1, CamelFileLength=22, CamelFileRelativePath=one.json, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data\one.json, CamelFileName=one.json, CamelFileNameOnly=one.json}, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false} ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = null } | org.apache.activemq.broker.util.LoggingBrokerPlugin | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:54712@61616
2016-06-24 07:13:39,397 | INFO  | Sending message: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 7, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:ThomasLaptop-54826-1466766792576-1:4:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:ThomasLaptop-54826-1466766792576-1:4:1:1, destination = queue://tripRequest.getCancellationRequest.v1.0, transactionId = null, expiration = 1466766820394, timestamp = 1466766819394, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = temp-queue://ID:ThomasLaptop-54826-1466766792576-1:4:1, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@65f79dd4, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = <request><id>259</id></request>} | org.apache.activemq.broker.util.LoggingBrokerPlugin | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:54846@61616
```

When the text one arrives, I get a converter error:

```
org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.xxx.trip.request.messaging.status.TripRequestUpdateStatusListener.handle(javax.jms.TextMessage)]
Bean [com.xxx.trip.request.messaging.status.TripRequestUpdateStatusListener@5a08d301]
; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [javax.jms.TextMessage] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[197], headers={CamelFileLastModified=1466448102155, CamelFileParent=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data, CamelFilePath=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data\two.json, CamelFileLength=22, jms_destination=queue://tripRequest.updateStatus.v1.0, jms_priority=4, CamelFileAbsolute=true, jms_timestamp=1466767729354, CamelFileName=two.json, jms_redelivered=true, jms_deliveryMode=2, JMSXDeliveryCount=7, CamelFileNameConsumed=two.json, breadcrumbId=ID-ThomasLaptop-55205-1466767725209-0-4, BrokerPath=localhost, jms_replyTo=temp-queue://ID:ThomasLaptop-55210-1466767727833-1:1:1, CamelFileRelativePath=two.json, jms_correlationId=Camel-ID-ThomasLaptop-55205-1466767725209-0-6, id=1b46ad3a-5e61-e4d0-94bd-111807169bb1, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data\two.json, jms_expiration=1466767749354, jms_messageId=ID:ThomasLaptop-55210-1466767727833-1:1:2:1:2, CamelFileNameOnly=two.json, timestamp=1466767742914}]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:94) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:66) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:721) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:681) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:315) [spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:253) [spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) [spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1150) [spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1047) [spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [javax.jms.TextMessage] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[197], headers={CamelFileLastModified=1466448102155, CamelFileParent=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data, CamelFilePath=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data\two.json, CamelFileLength=22, jms_destination=queue://tripRequest.updateStatus.v1.0, jms_priority=4, CamelFileAbsolute=true, jms_timestamp=1466767729354, CamelFileName=two.json, jms_redelivered=true, jms_deliveryMode=2, JMSXDeliveryCount=7, CamelFileNameConsumed=two.json, breadcrumbId=ID-ThomasLaptop-55205-1466767725209-0-4, BrokerPath=localhost, jms_replyTo=temp-queue://ID:ThomasLaptop-55210-1466767727833-1:1:1, CamelFileRelativePath=two.json, jms_correlationId=Camel-ID-ThomasLaptop-55205-1466767725209-0-6, id=1b46ad3a-5e61-e4d0-94bd-111807169bb1, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data\two.json, jms_expiration=1466767749354, jms_messageId=ID:ThomasLaptop-55210-1466767727833-1:1:2:1:2, CamelFileNameOnly=two.json, timestamp=1466767742914}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:124) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:112) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:90) ~[spring-jms-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

My camel route:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

  <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <!-- 
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://mq1.cloud.local:61616"/>
    <property name="userName" value="admin"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxxx"/>
     -->
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
  </bean>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <endpoint uri="dozer:buildApproveTripRequest?sourceModel=one.One&amp;targetModel=generated.TripRequestUpdateStatus&amp;marshalId=generated&amp;unmarshalId=oneOne&amp;mappingFile=buildApproveTripRequest.xml" id="buildApproveTripRequest"/>
  <dataFormats>
    <json library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="one.One" id="oneOne"/>
    <jaxb contextPath="generated" id="generated"/>
  </dataFormats>
  <route id="buildApproveTripRequest">
    <from uri="file://C:\Users\Thom\git\brms-poc-esb\rule-cancel\data"/>
    <log message="Processing ${file:name}"/>
    <to ref="buildApproveTripRequest"/>
    <log message="Handling unmarshal ${body}"/>
    <to uri="activemq:queue:tripRequest.updateStatus.v1.0?exchangePattern=InOut"/>
    <log message="Update Status responded ${out.body}"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Here's the transformer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
    <configuration>
        <wildcard>false</wildcard>
    </configuration>
    <mapping>
        <class-a>one.One</class-a>
        <class-b>generated.TripRequestUpdateStatus</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>tripId</a>
            <b>id</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <class-a>org.apache.camel.component.dozer.ExpressionMapper</class-a>
        <class-b>generated.TripRequestUpdateStatus</class-b>
        <field custom-converter-id="_expressionMapping" custom-converter-param="simple:Approved">
            <a>expression</a>
            <b>status</b>
        </field>
        <field custom-converter-id="_expressionMapping" custom-converter-param="simple:lgtc">
            <a>expression</a>
            <b>updatedBy.source</b>
        </field>
        <field custom-converter-id="_expressionMapping" custom-converter-param="simple:1">
            <a>expression</a>
            <b>updatedBy.value</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

I can't be the only one experiencing this.

Comment: Is it possible to setup a github repo demonstrating the issue? It would be easier for someone to help this way

Comment: Please add your code to your question.

Comment: @ManoDestra code attached. Thanks!

Comment: @ltsallas code attached. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any code, just XML files. Need to see the code you're using.

Comment: @ManoDestra that's the code. It's a camel blueprint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the option `jmsMessageType=Text` on the JMS endpoints to tell Camel to use text based JMS messages.

See the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/jms

You can also convert the message body to `String` before sending to the JMS endpoint using:

```
 <convertBodyTo type="String"/>
```